# Get a list of all measures in all pages a pbix uses?

Tags: powerbi, tabular, ssas-tabular

I have several .pbix where I consume from  a tabular SSAS. Therefore I can’t see the data:

I only see:

[image]

I connect to cubes that have hundreds of **tables** and **measures**, but I only use a subset of them… I want to know which **measures** and **columns** I actually use from the cube (so far I am doing this by clicking every visual and just writing down the names on the ‘Visualizations’ section; very time consuming!).

Is there an automated way to retrieve all the **measures** and **columns** a .pbix is using?